# Reference type and storage duration

Tags: c++, storage-duration

First, I quote the definition of storage duration (sec. 3.7.1/1 N3797):

> Storage duration is the property of an object that defines the minimum
>   potential lifetime of the storage containing the object.

But 3.7.1/3 said:

> The storage duration categories apply to references as well.

It is curious. I thought reference has no representation in memory at all. I also thought an objects and only objects represents in memory (sec. 1.8/1):

> An object is a region of storage.

What is the point of introducing storage duration concept to a reference?

Comment: References are usually represented in memory as pointers: they too have a storage and lifetime.

Comment: It's unspecified whether a reference takes up storage. A reference is not an object.  ("An X is a Y" does not imply "A Y is an X"). Your second quote does not appear in N3337 ; it must have been added since then, and it seems badly-worded as you point out. Presumably the intent is that the lifetime of references is defined in the same way as the lifetime of objects in each of the storage categories.

Comment: @MattMcNabb All quotes are from N3797

Comment: Yes, that comes after N3337

Comment: Imagine that references are pointers in disguise and they become easier to understand.

Comment: @NeilKirk What is the difference pointer between reference? Is there at all?

Comment: A reference has different syntax and must bind to an existing object - there is no equivalent to null pointer. A const reference can bind to a temporary object and extend its lifetime. Otherwise a reference is almost the same as a `T *const` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From §8.3.2/4:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage.

So if a reference does require some storage, the lifetime of that storage corresponds to the reference's storage duration.

Comment: But if reference does not required storage what does storage duration for reference mean in that case?